# How to get distinct strings from column in big query

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a table that represents:

```
orders | store_name | average_order_size
35       ABCD         2
41       XYZ          3
43       ABCD         2
85       HIJ          12
23       HIJ          12
34       XYZ          3
78       ABCD         2
```

I am trying to select unique names of each store `store_name`, with the sum of orders, and average order size

displaying:

```
sum_orders | store_name | average_order_size
156          ABCD         2
75           XYZ          3
108          HIJ          12
```

`orders` is a float, `average_order_size` is an int, and `store_name` is an object, so I don't see why my below query isn't working.

I am trying:

```
SELECT DISTINCT store_name as store_name, 
SUM(orders) as sum_orders 
FROM `a_database.database` 
GROUP BY store_name
```

but am receiving error of: `Cannot GROUP BY literal values at [position identifier]` (position identifier is arbitrary). I can't seem to find a concrete explanation that makes sense for this.

Any idea how I can accomplish this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: based on your edit - looks like you see now why it did not work for you. right?

Comment: Yes, I'm catching that now. It was a late night and it slipped me entirely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use below instead

```
SELECT store_name, 
  SUM(orders) as sum_orders,
  AVG(average_order_size) as average_order_size 
FROM `a_database.database` 
GROUP BY store_name
```

if applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]